# Old user info keeps coming back on M1 MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

I bought my M1 MacBook Air, second hand, and not only the host name keeps coming back after several factory resets (one of them erasing the partition), but also, an old email, that I don't recognize keeps coming back to settings --> user accounts.

I have to delete this old email, and rename "hostname", every time I factory reset may Mac. This is very strange. Do you guys have any idea how to get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: It could be that the previous owner hasn't removed the device from his Apple ID?

Comment: I bought the Mac at a 2nd hand shop, the previous owner removed is Apple ID from the Mac. there was no old Apple ID on the machine and I was able to set up my one before paying.

Is this equivalent to him removing the Mac from his Apple ID?

Comment: If he hadn't removed is Apple ID, I shouldn't be able to set it up as my one. right?

Answer (score -1):

what you mean with erase the partition? Do you have two partitions on your HD? One with the system and one with your Documents for example?

The normal way to give away a used Mac would be:

1. Start in recovery mode.
2. Enter the credentials of the former user in the recovery disk assistant
3. Erase the HD with the Disk Utility
4. Reinstall the system

This is roughly what you should do yourself, to have a clean system. Or the seller should have done it, before giving the MacBook over to you. With this CleanInstall there will be no leftovers anymore of the previous owner. But a CleanInstall has some pitfalls. Of course you have to make a backup first.

Do you have several users in `System Preferences` > `Users & Groups`?

Greetings

marek